# Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app

Tags: php, google-signin

I have implemented sign-in with google for my client using [google-api-php-client-2.4.0](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases).

The implementation was quite straight forward from the documentations. I have used the following code and it is working fine. The flow is (a)set the credentials and the scopes, (b) redirect to google url, (c) google provides a code (d) get token from code (e) get the required info using the token.

```
require_once("../../plugins/server/google-api-php-client-2.4.0/vendor/autoload.php");    

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId('*****');
    $client->setClientSecret('*****');
    $client->setRedirectUri("*****");

    $client->addScope("email");
    $client->addScope("profile");
    
    if (isset($_GET['code']))
    {
        $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
        $client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);
      
        //get profile info
        $google_oauth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
        $google_account_info = $google_oauth->userinfo->get();
        print_r($google_account_info);        
    }
    else
    {      
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
        exit;
    }
```

Though the above code I used is working fine, I am not sure whether this is the correct approach.  I am confused because, many code samples available in internet, uses the following approach to get the token. i.e., it does not use the token directly from the code. Instead, it is again redirecting to the same page and using the token.

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
  exit;
}


if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
     $token_data = $client->verifyIdToken();
   }
```

Can you help me to confirm whether my approach is fine and I can go ahead with it. Thanks.

Note: I could see from the code of the library, authenticate is deprecated method. Therefore, may be the code samples available in internet are old.

Comment: That depends on what OIDC flow you're using (Authorization Code Flow, Implicit Flow, a Hybrid Flow, etc - Google names one of them as "Basic Flow" but I forget which).

Comment: I am just trying to identify who is the logged in user. Since the application does not have a login system, we are  depending on google login in.  Once we identify the user, I do not need to communicate with google servers, except for next login when session time out occurs